# Mocking gives, Actually there were zero interations with this mock

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

Test when we run as a single test, it works perfect, but when it bundles with other tests, it gives Actually there were zero interations with this Mock. Also notice only one such method the error whereas other tests passes though same Verify case is used.

```
public class SubjectScheduleScreenPresenterTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private SubjectScheduleScreenPresenter presenter;

    @Mock
    private Context context;

    @Mock
    private SubjectScheduleScreenView view;

    @Mock
    private Payment payment;

    @Mock
    private UserDB userDB;

    @Mock
    private Calendar calendar;
    @Mock
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    private APIInterface apiInterface;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        apiInterface = NetworkContext.getInstance().getService(APIInterface.class);

    }

    @After
    public void afterMethod(){
        this.presenter = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void gotoPaytmTest(){
        double amount = 2.0, latitude =78.35,longitude = 78.50;
        int subjectId=2,tutorId = 2;

        Mockito.when(userDB.getValueFromSqlite("email",1)).thenReturn("jayakishan100@gmail.com");
        Mockito.when(userDB.getValueFromSqlite("userId",1)).thenReturn("38");

        presenter.gotoPaytm(amount,subjectId,tutorId,latitude,longitude,calendar,editor);
        Call call = apiInterface.getOrderId();

        try {
            Response<SessionBooking> sessionBookingResponse = call.execute();
            SessionBooking sessionBooking =sessionBookingResponse.body();

//            Mockito.verify(payment).callPaytm(sessionBooking.getOrderId(),userDB.getValueFromSqlite("email",1),
//                    amount,context,Integer.parseInt(userDB.getValueFromSqlite("userId",1)),-1,subjectId,latitude,longitude,
//                    calendar,editor);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void getSubjectDataTestSuccess(){

        int searchId = 2,from = 1;
        presenter.getSubjectData(searchId,from);

        ScheduleSubject scheduleSubject = new ScheduleSubject(searchId);
        Call call = apiInterface.getSubjectDataForScheduling(scheduleSubject);

        try {
            Response<ScheduleSubject> scheduleSubjectResponse =call.execute();
            ScheduleSubject scheduleSubject1 = (ScheduleSubject) scheduleSubjectResponse.body();
            Mockito.verify(view).setValues(from,scheduleSubject1.getSubjectName().trim(), scheduleSubject1.getPrice());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Test
    public void getSubjectDataTestFailure(){

        int searchId = -3,from = 1;
        presenter.getSubjectData(searchId,from);

        ScheduleSubject scheduleSubject = new ScheduleSubject(searchId);
        Call call = apiInterface.getSubjectDataForScheduling(scheduleSubject);

        try {
            Response<ScheduleSubject> scheduleSubjectResponse =call.execute();
            ScheduleSubject scheduleSubject1 = (ScheduleSubject) scheduleSubjectResponse.body();
            Mockito.verify(view).setValues(from,scheduleSubject1.getSubjectName().trim(), scheduleSubject1.getPrice());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

`getSubjectDataTestSuccess` is alone method gives me error while other test being passed.

Comment: firstly, there is no test with name `getDatabaseTestSuccess` that you have mentioned. secondly, tests are exculted in the alphabetical order of method names by default. So one of the reason it works individually and not as a whole could be that,  previous tests are messing up with the data that you are using in other tests.

Comment: My fault, its subjectDataTestSuccess. When i run this whole Test it works well, when with other tests bundles, it wont and gives me the error i mentioned. Those tests have nothing in common, which could mess up.